# How can i check which resources are using Azure Metadata Services?

Tags: azure

Ive had an email from MS as below, How can i get a list of whats using Azure Instance Metadata Services?

You're receiving this notice because you use Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) Attestation endpoint with your applications.

Immediate action is required to avoid service failure if your application has been pinned to the Baltimore CyberTrust Root CA.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a general way to get this list, it depends upon what OS you're using + what all is installed on your VM. Because IMDS isn't authenticated on any cloud provider, it isn't easy to generate an exact list. Instead the detection is simply "At least 1 process in this VM used this feature recently".

The action items at a high level are:

1. Do you own code that uses the IMDS Attested Data feature, and also engage in certificate pinning? If yes, you need to make changes to what certificate you are pinning. Also, consider no longer pinning certs. It isn't a great best practice, and will prevent this from being an issue for you if the certificates change again in the future.
2. If you use software that depends on this feature, you should be on the lookout for notifications to install updates from any of your vendors. If you don't hear from anyone, and regularly install your updates it will be fine.

The full answer is a bit too much for stack overflow as it varies by system, and is continually being updated since the original notifications have caused confusion. I recommend that people check this link, and provide feedback for updates on anything that isn't clear enough yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/878907/azure-instance-metadata-service-attested-data-cert.html